# Multiple arithmetic operations efficiently on NumPy

Tags: python, performance, loops, numpy

I have the following data for a Python program.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(28)

n = 100000
d = 60

S = np.random.rand(n)
O = np.random.rand(n, d, d)
p = np.random.rand()
mask = np.where(S < 0.5)
```

And I want to run the following algorithm:

```
def method1():
    sum_p = np.zeros([d, d])
    sum_m = np.zeros([d, d])

    for k in range(n):
        s = S[k] * O[k]
        sum_p += s
        if(S[k] < 0.5):
            sum_m -= s

    return p * sum_p + sum_m
```

This is a minimal example, but the code in `method1()` is supposed to be run many times in my project, so I would like to rewrite it in a more pythonic way, to make it as efficient as possible. I have tried with the following method:

```
def method2():
    sall = S[:, None, None] * O
    return p * sall.sum(axis=0) - sall[mask].sum(axis=0)
```

But, although this method performs better with low values of `d`, when `d=60` it does not provide good times:

```
# To check that both methods provide the same result.
In [1]: np.sum(method1() == method2()) == d*d 
Out[1]: True

In [2]: %timeit method1()
Out[2]: 801 ms ± 2.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit method2()
Out[3]: 1.91 s ± 6.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Do you have any other ideas to optimize this method?

(As additional information, the variable `mask` is supposed to be used in other parts of my final code, so I don't need to consider it inside the code of `method2` for the time computation.)

Comment: Did you try numba to compile it on the fly?

Comment: No. I will try it, but my primary interest is to rewrite the code in the most efficient way rather than this.

Comment: It looks like [numpy overhead can be significant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093073/why-is-numpy-sum-10-times-slower-than-the-operator?rq=1)

Comment: With these sizes memory management issues dominate.  On my modest machine I can't use `method2` because of memory error in the `S*O` step.  We've seen in other SO that itertive solutions can be faster when the alternative creates arrays that are too big.

Comment: I  think method 1 is near optimal